# No se insertan los datos desde PHP/PDO a Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Quiero saber si este código está bien o falta algo ya que NO inserta los datos en la base, sin embargo aparece el mensaje de que los datos han sido insertados:

- Uso Microsoft Windows.
- Microsoft SQL Server.
- Visual Studio Code.
- XAMMP (PHP 7.0 + Apache)

Aquí esta el código donde creo que tengo el problema:

```
<?php include 'conexion.php';

$conexion = conexion(); 
$claveGrupal = $_POST['claveGrupal']; 
$nombreGrupal = $_POST['nombreGrupal']; 
$fechaRegistro = $_POST['fechaRegistroGrupal']; 
$horaRegistro = $_POST['horaRegistroGrupal']; 
$responsable = $_POST['responsableRPEGrupal']; 
$fechaDelGrupal = $_POST['fechaDelGrupal']; 
$valorGrupal = $_POST['valorGrupal'];

try { $consulta = "INSERT INTO T.GRUPALES(CLAVE_GRUPAL,NOMBRE_GRUPAL,FECHA_REGISTRO,HORA_REGISTRO,RPE_RESPONSABLE,FECHA_GRUPAL,VALOR_GRUPAL)VALUES('$claveGrupal','$nombreGrupal','$fechaRegistro', '$horaRegistro', '$responsable', '$fechaDelGrupal','$valorGrupal');";


$ejecutar = $conexion->prepare($consulta);

$ejecutar->execute(array(":claveGrupal"=>$claveGrupal,":nombreGrupal"=>$nombreGrupal,":fechaRegistro"=>$fechaRegistro,":horaRegistro"=>$horaRegistro,":responsable"=>$responsable,":fechaDelGrupal"=>$fechaDelGrupal,":valorGrupal"=>$valorGrupal));


echo '<script language="JavaScript">';  
echo 'alert("GUARDADO!!!!!");';  echo '</script>';

} catch(Exception $e)

{
    header("Location: index.html"); }

$conexion=null; ?>
```

Según yo, la conexión la tengo bien ya que en otra página me muestra una tabla con los datos que tiene insertados.

Ésta sería la conexión con PDO:

```
<?php
  function conexion()
  {
    try
    { 
      $conexion = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=192.168.1.103;Database=Tutorias", "oscar", "OSCAREFREN");
      //$conexion = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=192.168.1.103;Database=Tutorias", "oscar", "OSCAREFREN");

        return $conexion;
    }    
    catch (PDOException $e) 
    {
      header("Location: index.html");
    }
  }
?>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme y si gustan que agregue algo más díganme para hacerlo.

Comment: Por favor mira [ask]. Cual es el problema con este codigo? tira un error? que es lo que no hace bien?

Comment: Lo siento, es mi primera pregunta a lo que me referia es si mi codigo esta bien lo que pasa es que sale el mensaje de no se guardaron los datos entonces queria saber si el codigo esta bien

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema esta en como haces el prepare. Debería ser así:

> SI UTILIZAS UNA CONEXIÓN TIPO PDO:

```
$consulta = "INSERT INTO T.GRUPALES(CLAVE_GRUPAL, NOMBRE_GRUPAL, FECHA_REGISTRO, HORA_REGISTRO, RPE_RESPONSABLE, FECHA_GRUPAL, VALOR_GRUPAL)VALUES(:claveGrupal, :nombreGrupal, :fechaRegistro, :horaRegistro, :responsable, :fechaDelGrupal, :valorGrupal)";

$ejecutar = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
```

Lo demas creo que funciona, sino haz esto:

```
$ejecutar->bindParam(':claveGrupal', $claveGrupal);
$ejecutar->bindParam(':nombreGrupal', $nombreGrupal);
$ejecutar->bindParam(':fechaRegistro', $fechaRegistro);
$ejecutar->bindParam(':horaRegistro', $horaRegistro);
$ejecutar->bindParam(':responsable', $responsable);
$ejecutar->bindParam(':fechaDelGrupal', $fechaDelGrupal);
$ejecutar->bindParam(':valorGrupal', $valorGrupal);

$ejecutar->execute();
```

Fuente [documentación de php](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

> SI UTILIZAS UNA CONEXIÓN TIPO MySQLI:

```
$consulta = "INSERT INTO T.GRUPALES(CLAVE_GRUPAL, NOMBRE_GRUPAL, FECHA_REGISTRO, HORA_REGISTRO, RPE_RESPONSABLE, FECHA_GRUPAL, VALOR_GRUPAL)VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?";

$ejecutar = $conexion->prepare($consulta);

$ejecutar->bind_param('iiiiiii', $claveGrupal, $nombreGrupal, $fechaRegistro, $horaRegistro, $responsable, $fechaDelGrupal, $valorGrupal);

$ejecutar->execute();
```

> ACTUALIZACIÓN:
>
> Añadido método para conexiones tipo MySQLI.

Comment: sigue sin funcionar, realize lo primero y segia igual, despues le agrege lo segundo y ahora me marca un error:Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindParam() on null

Comment: Ya la cambie pero nada sigue diciendo el mismo error, y si los datos si llegan a php ya me asegure de eso al igual que la conexion si esta conectada ya que me muestra datos de una tabla :(

Comment: Espera, ¿que tipo de conexión estas utilizando? ¿MSQLI o PDO?

Comment: PDO ahora la agrego

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucione al parecer era tomar los datos del Java y pasarlos al php y listo ya estan los datos, actualizo el codigo si es que algun dia es de ayuda para alguien. Gracias!

Comment: No actualices tu pregunta con nuevo codigo (y menos que ya funciona). En su lugar, acepta la respuesta que te arregla el problema, o pon tu propia respuesta explicando el problema y la solucion al mismo. mira por favor [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Tu código necesita algunas modificaciones para que los errores en las consultas se puedan interceptar mediante bloques `try`/`catch` como esperas que ocurra.

Empezamos con el archivo de conexión:

```
<?php
function conexion()
{
    try {
        /* Establecemos la conexión y proporcionamos una opción
           para indicar que los errores en las consultas produzcan excepciones */
        $conexion = new PDO(
            "sqlsrv:Server=192.168.1.103;Database=Tutorias",
            "oscar",
            "OSCAREFREN",
            [
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            ]
        );
        return $conexion;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
    /* Mostramos el mensaje de error (creo que es importante no ignorarlo) */
        die('Error de conexión: ' . htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
        /* header("Location: index.html"); */
    }
}
/* No es necesario cerrar con ? > los script con sólo código */
```

A partir de ahora un error SQL producirá la esperada excepción.

Además, en tu código usas concatenación de cadenas en vez de las consultas preparadas, aunque haces el paso de `prepare` y luego el de `execute` con los parámetros. Pero al no haber marcadores en el SQL es probable que eso provocara la excepción de "Marcador no existente".

El código corregido sería:

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';

$conexion = conexion();
try {
    $consulta = '
      INSERT INTO T.GRUPALES (
        CLAVE_GRUPAL,
        NOMBRE_GRUPAL,
        FECHA_REGISTRO,
        HORA_REGISTRO,
        RPE_RESPONSABLE,
        FECHA_GRUPAL,
        VALOR_GRUPAL
      ) VALUES (
        :claveGrupal,
        :nombreGrupal,
        :fechaRegistro,
        :horaRegistro,
        :responsable,
        :fechaDelGrupal,
        :valorGrupal
      )
    ';
    /* Preparamos la consulta */
    $ejecutar = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
    /* La ejecutamos pasando los marcadores (tipo PDO::PARAM_STR por defecto */
    $ejecutar->execute([
        ":claveGrupal" => $_POST['claveGrupal'],
        ":nombreGrupal" => $_POST['nombreGrupal'],
        ":fechaRegistro" => $_POST['fechaRegistroGrupal'],
        ":horaRegistro" => $_POST['horaRegistroGrupal'],
        ":responsable" => $_POST['responsableRPEGrupal'],
        ":fechaDelGrupal" => $_POST['fechaDelGrupal'],
        ":valorGrupal" => $_POST['valorGrupal'],
    ]);
    /* No llegará aquí si se produjo una excepción */
    echo '<script language="JavaScript">alert("GUARDADO!!!!!");</script>';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    /* Mostramos el mensaje de error (creo que es importante no ignorarlo) */
    die('Error SQL: ' . htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
    /* header("Location: index.html");*/
}

/* No es necesario cerrar ? > en un script con sólo código */
```

Ahora tu código no alcanzará la zona que genera el mensaje "GUARDADO!!!!!" si se produce un error en la consulta (registro duplicado, formato de fecha incorrecto, error de sintaxis, campo o tabla no existente, etc).

Además, he agregado el mensaje de error para que no se pierda y puedas depurar la aplicación.

PD: Te recomiendo encarecidamente que sigas las recomendaciones [PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) para el formato y estilo de código. Te facilitará la lectura y depuración del código.